# Running command line with c# not working

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I have the following C# code that runs a command line:

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
si.FileName = @"Lib\my_program.exe";

si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
si.CreateNoWindow = true;

si.Arguments = "my args";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = si;
p.Start();
```

It works perfect on one computer, but when running it on different computer - nothing happens.

When trying to run it via the command line at the problematic computer - it also works fine.

all the paths are correct and I run it with an admin permission.

What can go wrong? maybe some environment variables? or computer's security issues?

Comment: Are you sure the current directory is set right? Try creating a FileInfo object on the exe path and ask if it exists.

Comment: Are you sure 2nd computer has the same framework version or upper?

Comment: You stay out of trouble by *always* specifying the full path (like c:\foo\bar\baz.exe) and *always* setting the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.  Use the Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location property to build the path.

Answer (score 1):

As it works when running from the command line, I would say that your application shortcut is running the program with a different working directory (so the relative path `Lib\my_program.exe` doesn't resolve to an existing program).

More generally, [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can throw various exceptions (probably `FileNotFoundException` in this case) so I suggest you wrap the code with a try/catch block and write the exception to `Console.Error` or display an error dialog.

Comment: Definitely put in a `try/catch` because this will more than likely answer your question on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Check here ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariable["Path"] . If this doesn't have the "my_program.exe"'s parent folder. Then probably it is not knowing the location. Remember, here  "Path" is case sensitive. Thanks go to my senior who cleared my doubt today on this one.